# How to apply Thevenin's theorem to the equivalent two-port circuit of receiving antenna?

Tags: circuit-analysis, antenna

[image]
[image]

This circuit is adopted from page 633 of the book of "Field and Wave Electromagnetics, 2ed" written by David K. Cheng.  According to his description:

[image]

The equivalent internal resistance obtained by Thevenin's theorem should be $$Z_{22}-\frac{Z^2_{12}}{Z_{11}}$$. And I have confirmed this equation is right by finding another paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTuDN.png) giving the same equation. However, it seems to me, with shorting $$Z_{L}$$, it should be $$\frac{Z_{12}V_1/Z_{11}}{\frac{V_1}{Z_{11}-Z_{12}+\frac{1}{1/Z_{12}+1/({Z_{22}-Z_{12})}}}}=\frac{Z^2_{12}}{Z_{11}Z_{22}}(Z_{22}-Z_{12})+\frac{Z_{12}}{Z_{11}}(Z_{11}-Z_{12})$$, which clearly not leads to equation (11-101). Which part of my derivation is wrong?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTuDN.png) Collin, R. E. "Limitations of the Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits for a receiving antenna." IEEE Antennas and Propagation Magazine 45, no. 2 (2003): 119-124.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the current i2 is the same as the current passing through V1 which is not the case. The current passing through V1 is not the same as the one passing through Voc.

You apply the current divider rule to get i2 from i1, when shorting ZL it is multiplying the current by Z12/Z22. That is multiplying the final result by Z22/Z12 and you will get the right answer.

Comment: Thx! It seems that I had this wrong understanding about Thevenin's theorem for years...